# Angular 8 web app failing to deploy to heroku

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku

I feel like my Angular app is fully setup for deploying to Heroku, but for some reason it just hangs during the build process and never continues - eventually resulting in a Build Failed message, but no logs.

Here is an excerpt of the heroku logs --tail:

```
   -----> Build
   Detected both "build" and "heroku-postbuild" scripts
   Running heroku-postbuild

   > flux-admin@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild /tmp/build_d18bae1ef2310aacfb6851eddfeab6d1
   > ng build --prod

   Generating ES5 bundles for differential loading...
   ES5 bundle generation complete.

   chunk {0} runtime-es2015.edb2fcf2778e7bf1d426.js (runtime) 1.45 kB [entry] [rendered]
   chunk {0} runtime-es5.edb2fcf2778e7bf1d426.js (runtime) 1.45 kB [entry] [rendered]
   chunk {1} main-es2015.b5ce220634282bd1233e.js (main) 1010 kB [initial] [rendered]
   chunk {1} main-es5.b5ce220634282bd1233e.js (main) 1.08 MB [initial] [rendered]
   chunk {2} polyfills-es2015.2987770fde9daa1d8a2e.js (polyfills) 36.4 kB [initial] [rendered]
   chunk {3} polyfills-es5.df1101cc1e7b588877f8.js (polyfills-es5) 122 kB [initial] [rendered]
   chunk {4} styles.c1cdb3f05888558b2d70.css (styles) 60.6 kB [initial] [rendered]
   Date: 2019-11-23T15:43:44.636Z - Hash: 80ca71603894ea5db348 - Time: 114953ms
```

That is where it just hangs.

Here is my package.json file:

```
"name": "flux-admin",
"version": "1.0.0",
"scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "start": "node server.js",
  "build": "ng build",
  "test": "ng test",
  "lint": "ng lint",
  "e2e": "ng e2e",
  "heroku-prebuild": "",
  "heroku-postbuild": "ng build --prod"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
  "@angular/cdk": "~7.3.3",
  "@angular/cli": "~8.3.19",
  "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
  "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.14",
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.19",
  "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
  "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
  "@angular/material": "^7.3.3",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
  "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
  "core-js": "^2.5.4",
  "path": "^0.12.7",
  "rxjs": "~6.5.3",
  "express": "^4.17.1",
  "rxjs-compat": "^6.4.0",
  "tslib": "^1.9.0",
  "typescript": "~3.5.3",
  "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular/cli": "~8.3.19",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.14",
  "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
  "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
  "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
  "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
  "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
  "enhanced-resolve": "^3.3.0",
  "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
  "karma": "~4.0.0",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
  "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
  "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
  "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
  "protractor": "~5.4.0",
  "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
  "tslint": "~5.11.0",
  "typescript": "~3.5.3"
},
"engines": {
  "node": "11.10.0",
  "npm": "6.13.1"
}
```

My server.js file is the following:

```
//Install express server
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();


// Serve only the static files form the dist directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/flux-admin'));

app.get('/*', function(req,res) {

res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/dist/flux-admin/index.html'));
});

// Start the app by listening on the default Heroku port
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

Just in case I also added a Procfile:

```
web: node server.js
```

When I try and run `ng build --prod --aot` locally - it does complete successfully, so it just seems to not go onto the next step in the heroku deployment process (which I believe would be the `start` script).

Anything obvious wrong with my setup?

### UPDATE

After multiple attempts to try and get this deployed - I ended up degrading back to Angular 7, and it deployed with no problem!

I believe the issue must stem with the new way the `ng build --prod --aot` is run in Angular 8, but I am not at all sure why or what the cause is. So for now, I will just continue using Angular 7 and post a bug report.

Comment: In my heroku app in package.json I used `"postinstall": "ng build --prod --aot"` instead of `"heroku-postbuild"` script. It worked fine ~2 years ago, could you try it this way?

Comment: Yes, I had tried that previously. Was just trying `heroku-postbuild` to see if any change.

Comment: Try `"heroku-postbuild": "ng build --aot --configuration=production",`. Also get rid of `"heroku-prebuild": "",` if your not using it. Next stage after `heroku-postbuild` is `Pruning devDependencies` so maybe an issue there? Nothing jumps out.